# How to identify mysterious physics force affecting my objects?

Tags: physics, constraints

I have some connected rigid body objects (a ragdoll). When I let physics do its thing, the ragdoll doesn't just fall - it acts as if some mysterious force hits it.

While investigating what might be the cause for it, I realized there's something (mysterious force) that affects the ragdoll. It's positioned roughly where the ragdoll is. To demonstrage this, if I duplicate the ragdoll and move the duplicate 2m to the side, the duplicate doesn't hit that mysterious force.

Here's how it looks (first 10 frames, slowed down):
[image]

For completeness, I also tried just moving everything around, and indeed there seems to be something roughly 2.5 meters above the origin:

[YouTube video: Blender 2.9 mystery force affecting ragdoll falling down](https://youtu.be/NWSZXzFEUP8)

Before I rewatch *Stranger Things* and look for clues there, any suggestion on how to find what's causing this strange behavior? How to identify that invisible force?

FTR, Here's the [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z2gpvyAZ-LaWc4uT4P4M51KCMryK5rBm/view) in question.

Thanks.

Note: this is a followup to [a previous question I asked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215719/how-to-setup-reasonable-ragdoll-constraints-between-body-parts) - at that point, I thought the problem was with the constraints between the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The mysterious invisible force is 12 copies of your ragdoll.** They are not in your scene but in your blend file. It looks like these lost objects are still used for collision detection.

To get rid of the copies, select `Blender File` as *Display Mode* for the outliner. Look for *Objects* and expand it. If you select everything in the viewport, then you can easily see in the outliner which objects are used in the viewport. Delete the other unwanted copies.
[image: lost copies]

If you want to see the hidden copies, create a new file, delete everything and use *File → Append ...* to append the collections *RigidBodyContraints* and *RigidBodyWorld* from this file. These collections are used internally by Blender and are connected to the lost objects. This way you can append them easily to your scene.

[image: 13 ragdolls]<sup>Revealing the 12 hidden ragdolls</sup>

Comment: Amazing! I wrote a script to create the ragdoll, and ran it multiple times, but deleted all existing ragdoll objects in the beginning of the script. Can you think of a reason why they weren't "fully deleted"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered hundred of old objectd which were missing with the physics yet not appearing.
You can also go to `Orphan Data` as Display Mode for the outliner, there's a purge button that will remove stuff (Hopefully useless ones).